# Behavior of lesser known illegal M6800 opcodes

Tags: 6800, undocumented-opcodes

The M6800 had a few illegal opcodes, including the (in)famous `HCF` (Halt and Catch Fire). The following illegal opcodes were revealed in [BYTE Magazine, December 1977](https://spivey.oriel.ox.ac.uk/wiki/images-corner/1/1a/Undoc6800.pdf):

- `$14`: `NBA`
- `$87`: `STAA` immediate
- `$C7`: `STAB` immediate
- `$8F`: `STS` immediate
- `$CF`: `STX` immediate
- `$9D`/`$DD`: `HCF`

In addition, [this article](https://x86.fr/investigating-the-halt-and-catch-fire-instruction-on-motorola-6800/) reveals these additional illegal opcodes:

- `$15`: `NOP`
- `$CD`/`$ED`: `HCF` with slightly different behavior
- `$FD`: `HCF` but slower

Okay, that's all well and good. I only listed them all because the first article I linked to, from BYTE Magazine in December 1977, says the following:

> Some of those codes seem to be just NOPS: they do nothing. Others change the flags in the condition code register according to some pattern that is, as yet, undeciphered.

What are these additional illegal opcodes on the M6800, which are not listed above? And has someone deciphered their flag changing patterns in the intervening 42.5 years?

Comment: I guess it is like people collecting doorknobs.  I don't understand it, or the fascination with undocumented opcodes.  Sure you can investigate them and even use them, but to depend on them in real code is risky to the point of foolishness.  Just because you have a physical CPU where undocumented opcodes does such and such, other people will have the "same" CPU where such and such is something different.  Like doorknobs that don't have knobs. Still upvoting, though, because you did some research.

Comment: [visual 6800](http://www.visual6502.org/JSSim/expert-6800.html) should be the authoritative answer for what every instruction does.

Comment: @RichF Hehe, yeah, I've been down an illegal opcode rabbit hole lately after I accidentally used an MC6803 assembler for my MC6800 code, and it "optimized" my `JSR $0040` into an `HCF` (or a `JSR $40` as it's known on the 6803). It's just curiousity, albeit perhaps a morbid curiosity.

Comment: @KelvinSherlock Ah, perfect! I thought I'd need an FPGA or something, but this is great. Thank you.

Comment: @tobiasvl That would be *this*: https://tobiasvl.github.io/blog/choosing-the-wrong-m6800-assembler/ (yes, you are one of the only people to mention 'mc6800 hcf' enough for it to show up in a google search)

Comment: @RichF I think it could be the puzzle - to understand why the invalid opcode causes something. The 6502 had a couple, mostly useless ones, that were all converted to plain NOPs on the 65C02. OTOH, the Z-80 had a bunch of actually useful ones and, if you wanted portability, you needed to replicate them in future versions.

Comment: @RichF: Every Atari 2600 or Nintendo Entertainment System console that will ever be manufactured will either use the same arrangement of transistors, or a CPU emulator that was developed after many useful corner-case behaviors that occur as a result of this arrangement were analyzed.  Some undocumented instructions may e.g. cut the time and code space of an unrolled loop from eight bytes/13 cycles to six bytes/11 cycles, thus increasing by 15% the number of tiles the NES can draw during vertical blank.

Comment: @rbanffy: I wouldn't regard the ability to store (A and X), the ability to load A and X simultaneously, nor the ability to decrement a byte of memory and compare it with A, useless.  In fact, I'd regard all three of those as being more broadly useful than some of the more complicated instructions that were added to the 65C02.